# Magento 2.3 There is no Start option in Newsletter queue

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I want to send Newsletters via magento 2.3 newsletter. But in newsletter queue , no start action available
can anybody have a solution for this?. what should i do for resolve this? I didn't configure any extension for newsletters.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To manage the load on server, Magento sends it in queue via cron jobs. So there is no any start option. You simply need to schedule the start time and it will send it on specified time.
For more details on Queue scheduling please refer https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/newsletter-queue.html

In case if its still not sending you need to debug a bit

1. Check if cronjob is scheduled correctly for your Magento instance. For more details please refer https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-cronjob-schedule-tasks-magento-2.html
2. Check the timezone of your Magento instance.

Hope it was helpfull.
Thanks

Comment: Hi,Thank you Pathan.I have created new queue without date then start appears in action.

Comment: @Ravi, It helps. Thanks!